# Overwrite the file in the S3Bucket is not working when run a job through jar, but works in IDE(Eclipse)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I wish to read and overwrite the json file in S3bucket. I have implemented the below code in `MapReduce` using the `Eclipse IDE`. I am able to overwrite in the `S3Bucket` successfully.

Using `maven`, I built the jar and I ran the job in terminal at this time I am not able to overwrite in the `S3bucket`. It also doesn't throws any exception.

In short,

- When I run a job through eclipse I am able to overwrite but
- When I run a job through jar file I am not able to overwrite the file in S3Bucket.

  ```
  AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
   S3Sample.class.getResourceAsStream("AwsCredentials.properties")));

   try {
       System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");
       File file = new File(uploadFileName);

       s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                       bucketName, keyName, file));

    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {

       System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
      "means your request made it " +
      "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
      " for some reason.");
     // ... error handling based on exception details

    }
  ```

Please show me a way how to proceed this...

Comment: What exception you are getting. There must be a warning/exception getting logged somewhere!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Gyan. I am not getting any exception, the job run successfully in the terminal but in the S3bucket it is not overwritten(there is no update in the file)

Comment: The only difference I can see is that, in eclipse you will have some dependent jar; while server might have different different set of jar. Can you try creating fat jar and try?

Comment: Okay Gyan. I will try and let you know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Gyan, I've built the project using maven and in the target(under workspace folder)folder jar files has been created. This jar files consists of all dependencies which you said as fat jar. Please suggest me a way how to proceed this further

Comment: Kindly try to execute this jar on console, ideally this should work, because it has the same set of jars as of eclipse IDE. If this still does not work, then there is some other problem, which is preventing the program to write in S3.

Comment: I ran this job in the terminal, still the same issue. I created two projects based on this task 1) Pure mapreduce format like context.write way of writing in S3Bucket 2) Implemented the above java code in the MapReduce and then tried to write in the S3 Bucket.

Comment: PureMapreduce works fine in both eclipse as well as in terminal but the second way is not working in terminal but works in eclipse. Hope you've understood. Please give me some suggestion